# Changing a buttons colour on submit until new text is entered

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change the colour of a button when it is submitted, for a period of time until the whole process starts again ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? What is the process?

Comment: I would usually do something in the function where i want it to happen such as "document.getElementById('send_btn').style.background-colour="red" the problem is naturally once this executes it stays this way - is it possible to even put a timeout on the function?

Comment: You could use a callback in whatever function you want the button to change colors after. Or if you just want it to change colors after a certain time, you could use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place `element.style.backgroundColor = "color";` on different steps of the process. Example:

```js
function steps() {

  var button = document.getElementById("btn");

  button.style.backgroundColor = "orange";  

  setTimeout(function(){ button.innerHTML = "1"; }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function(){ button.innerHTML = "2"; }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function(){ button.innerHTML = "3"; }, 3000);

  setTimeout(function(){ button.style.backgroundColor = "tomato"; }, 4000);

  setTimeout(function(){  
    button.innerHTML = "click here";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue"; }, 6000);  

}
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: skyblue;  
}
```

```html
<button id=btn onclick="steps()">click here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('send_btn').style["background-color"]="red"
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('send_btn').style["background-color"] = ""
}, 1000) // 1000 - This value is in ms. (here time is 1second)
```